# Problems with "delete" keyword

Tags: c++, memory-management

In the `main` function

```
string reader_txt = "Readers.txt";
string book_txt = "Books.txt";

Reader * obj[10];

// *********** Reading Reader.txt

ifstream reader_input;
reader_input.open(reader_txt.c_str()); // open file

string reader_name;
string reader_category;
int reader_n_category;
int counter=0;

if(reader_input.is_open())
{
    while( getline(reader_input, reader_name, '\n') && getline(reader_input, reader_category, '\n'))
    {
        reader_n_category = atoi(reader_category.c_str());

        switch(reader_n_category)
        {
        case FANTASY:
            obj[counter++] = new fantasyReader(reader_name);
            break;
        case MYSTERY:
            obj[counter++] = new mysteryReader(reader_name);
            break;
        case HORROR:
            obj[counter++] = new horrorReader(reader_name);
            break;
        case SCIENCE:
            obj[counter++] = new scienceReader(reader_name);
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
    cout<<"Cannot open up the Readers.txt"<<endl;

reader_input.close();   // close file
```

`reader` is base class
`fantasyReader`, `horrorReader`, `mysteryReader`, `scienceReader` are derived class.

At the end of `main` I put:

```
for(int pos=0; pos < counter; pos++)
{
     delete obj[pos];  // compiling error, I don't know why
}
```

I get a compile error:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `"public: __thiscall Reader::~Reader(void)" (??1Reader@@QAE@XZ)` referenced in function `"public: void * __thiscall Reader::'scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GReader@@QAEPAXI@Z)`

This wouldn't work. How can or where should I write a `delete` statement?

Comment: In addition to the specific compiler error, can we see the declaration of the reader class?

Comment: @Will A: It has to be a C++ file because of `cout<<`, `ifstream` and `string`.

Comment: Please post the entire program. There's no way to know whether the error is e.g. in the Reader class because we cannot see the source. Please also quote the error message exactly as given by the compiler, for the same reason.

Comment: I can't cut/paste the code. So it is really hard to work out the error as I have to resolve so many other problems before I get to the error you are trying t describe. Any chance you can just put some code we can compile (is it that hard!).

Answer (score 3):

It's not a compile time error, but a linking error. You've declared the destructor of `Reader`, but not implemented it. You've got to implement the destructor in `Reader` even if it's a pure virtual one, like so:

```
class Reader {
public:
  virtual ~Reader() = 0;
};

Reader::~Reader() {}
```

Also remember (in case you haven't done it already) that a base class must **always** have its destructor set as `virtual`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a linking error, not a compiler error.

You forgot to define an implementation for `Reader`'s destructor.

Comment: The ever-popular confounding of compiling and linking strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

The `Reader` base class needs to have a public virtual destructor.  There may be other problems, but this is what I can gather from the incomplete code posted.

Comment: The lack of a `virtual` destructor would cause UB, but not a compilation error. The lack of a `public` destructor (and, for this, you'd have to have explicitly written a `private` or `protected` one) could cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the delete statement that is important. Have you defined the derived classes as virtual ones? Or, at least the have you declared the destructors as virtual?

Comment: you mean   virtual ~Reader()  ??

Comment: I don't see how virtual inheritance is relevant here, Michael.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Second, without virtual destructors similar linker errors will appear.